# Stuck on deleting 3 lines "shoot for the moon" in level 8

Tags: vim-adventures

Trying to pass level 8 and am stuck on the "shoot for the moon" puzzle where you have to delete three lines at once.

Comment: Perhaps you could elaborate?

Comment: Remember that commands can have a number before them to tell them to repeat. Try `3dd` or similar. (I don't know that puzzle, but I know Vim.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those interested, it was dG to delete to the end of the file (even though G alone moves you to the beginning of the last line). Hope that helps.