# How do I delete the last 3 lines in this text and pass level 7?

Tags: vim-adventures

I am playing level 7 of vim-adventures. 
I can start at the first character, the letter 'i', of this if statement.
I need to delete the last 3 lines that are marked in red.
I am only allowed 5 keystrokes once I am on the letter i.
[image: How to Delete the 3 red lines]

I am only allowed the following commands:

[image: vim commands I am allowed]

I would want to use the command `f}` to take the cursor directly to line 3 but for some reason that does not work. It seems to only let me use `f` for within the same line. 
So far, I have been able to reach the letter 'e' but only had 1 keystroke left.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have enough buttons¹ to solve this puzzle.

Hint 1

> There are two solutions. For both you need a button¹ which you still need to find.

Hint 2

> You have to get one yellow key² and unlock either the house on the left or the house above. One of those buttons¹ is enough to solve this puzzle

Hint 3

> When you either have the `%` button¹ or the `g` button¹ you have enough to solve this puzzle

Spoiler

> The full solution: [Vim-Adventures in level 7](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/294945/vim-adventures-in-level-7)

¹) = unlocked keyboard keys
²) = door unlocker